# Обвод контура объекта

Tags: unity3d

Нужно обвести контур объекта,а конкретно треугольник сгенерированный в коде,имею только координаты всех его точек.Вопрос: Каким образом можно обвести контур объекта или уменьшить его размер,зная только координаты вершин(LocalScale не работает,т.к. Mesh создается рандомный и углы тянутся "сферами")
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1)Пробовал использовать LineRenderer,возникла проблема острых углов как на изображении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2)пробовал использовать Shader outline, обводка не работает,просто окрашивает треугольник в цвет main color.
Подскажите,каким образом можно переписать LineRenderer,чтоб не "ехали" линии на острых углах,или как можно сделать обводку линиями аналогом LineRenderer.
Или каким образом можно уменьшить размер объекта зная только его координаты в формате Vector3

Как я вижу результат(без стрелки и букв):
Извиняюсь,если задал глупый вопрос,но правда искал попытки решения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если треугольник один требуется обводить, то можно вместо одной линии сделать 3, чтобы они на острых углах не выпирали рисуем их чуть короче и в точках ставим кружок шириной в линию.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, как вариант:
Сгенерируйте дубликат вашего треугольника и увеличьте его скейл:  обводка.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1.1f, 1.1f, 1.1f). В итоге у вас нарисуется ещё один такой же треугольник только чуть большего размера. Поиграйте со значениями, поменяйте цвет и получите обводку. Если треугольник планируется двигать, назначьте треугольник-обводку чайлдом для основного -
 обводка.transform.SetParent(треугольник.transform);

Comment: У меня треугольники углами соединены между собой,получается одна огромная фигура из треугольников,мне нужно,чтоб в старте например: они сужались или обводились(чтоб была сетка между треугольниками)Должна получится "разделитель треугольников" они как-бы визуально не вплотную стоят(игра 2D)

Comment: @Stelette, не совсем понимаю. Описанную вами задачу можно решить описанным мною способом. Если нужна обводка - делайте дубликат и увеличивайте его размер. Если нужно просто сузить, чтобы было расстояние - уменьшайте скейл самого треугольника в старте.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге проще было переписать скрипт с нуля,и создавать mesh изначально чуть меньше заданного размера